# What does the phrase “belong together” mean?

Tags: usage, phrase-meaning

I always think of the meaning of “belong” in one of the following ways:

- as a verb: used to say that someone or something should be in a particular place or situation;
- [phrasal verb]: belong to (someone) means to be owned by someone; belong to (something) means to be a member of a club, organization, etc.

I was looking up for the meaning of the term **set** in google lately, and it goes like this:

> a number of things that belong together.

My confusion: "Belong together" to what? So, if I say “a set of commands”, according to this definition, it means a number of commands that belong together, but what do these commands belong to?

Comment: Note that *belong **together*** is not the same as *belong **to.*** If anything it's your first meaning: the items are linked together in some way.

Comment: 'They belong together' means 'it is appropriate/well that they should be knitted together (in a close relationship) or considered as being closely associated'. 'John and Ruth belong together' / 'The authors of CGEL consider that traditional present participles and gerunds belong / should be classified together'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It helped. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They belong to the group they form together. They do not "do" the belonging together, it is ***together*** that is the "destination" of belong. Just as when you say that:

> Your shoes ***belong in the closet***, not in the middle of the living room. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belong))

The belonging is not only about owning, but also about ***the appropriate, suitable place or environment or group of something/someone***, as you can see in the link from the dictionary provided.

Quoting *Collins*, [FreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/belong) explains:

> You can also use ***belong*** to say that ***someone or something is in the right place***. *Belong* is used ***on its own, or is followed by an adverbial phrase*** such as ***here, over there***, or ***in the next room***. [*I would add **together***].
>
> - The plates don't ***belong** in that cupboard.*
> - They need to feel they ***belong***.

When you say ***a set of commands***, you do not refer to owning or belonging, but to the fact that the commands form a group in which they function together, not individually.

Comment: I am not sure it is about a shared characteristic necessarily. It can be simply something that makes them unable to function separately. For example, it's no use buying a phone without buying a sim card or a charger together with it. They therefore come as a _**set**_.

Comment: Can I use “related” instead of “belong”? I am not really aware of any nuances in their difference btw.

Comment: "Related" is less strong than "belong". Not all related commands belong together. I would be careful to accurately express the interdependence of the commands. If it's a _set_, then _belong_ is more correct.

Comment: OK, so the things that are belong together kinda “complement” each other? Just like  cars components?

Comment: Yes, These commands will give the desired result, only if they work together. Separately they may have some action but which may be only a step towards the desired result.

Comment: I am glad you listened, I am feeling heard. Though, I have one last question: you mentioned “related” being less stronger than “belong”. What a reader with a reasonable amount of knowledge of the nuances between “related” and “belong" would comprehend if I were to say: "these commands are related to each other" instead of "these commands belong to each other"?

Comment: And this is my last answer, as this site is not a chat. If you say commands are related, they are similar in some things or share a common property or origin etc, but they can function separately. Whereas with "belong" you are saying they must function together.

Comment: Congratulations on being the top 1% on this site for this year. Thanks for your time.